# Hibernate: Insertar nuevo registro con nueva relación

Tags: java, hibernate

Os explico el problema que estoy teniendo y como no tengo mucha experiencia en Hibernate no veo como solucionar. He intentado buscar en google pero no he sabido encontrar la solución.

Tengo una tabla clientes que tiene una relación uno a muchos con una tabla contratos.
En la tabla contratos se guarda el id del cliente y puede haber muchos contratos con el mismo id de cliente.

He mapeado las clases en Hibernate de la siguiente manera:

En la clase Cliente tengo el siguiente getter:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="cliente", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OrderBy("fechaContrato DESC")
public List<Contrato> getContratos(){
    return contratos;
}
```

En la clase Contrato tengo el siguiente getter:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="Cliente",insertable=true,nullable=true,unique=true,updatable=true)
public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente.get();
}
```

En principio creo que el mapeo esta bien. Cuando leo un cliente me llena la lista de contratos y si leo un contrato me obtiene tambien los datos del cliente. Si en un cliente existente le añado un contrato nuevo me crea el nuevo contrato con el id de cliente. Así que esto parece funcionar bien.

Mi problema llega cuando quiero crear un nuevo cliente con un nuevo contrato. Lo estoy intentando crear a la vez. Es decir, creo un nuevo objeto cliente, añado un nuevo objeto contrato en su lista de contratos y hago un saveorupdate del cliente. El orden en que hibernate me hace las operaciones es:

1- Insertar contrato

2- Update cliente

En este punto, el programa falla, porque el cliente aún no existe!

Hay alguna manera para hacer que hibernate antes de nada inserte el nuevo cliente? O se tiene que hacerlo manualmente?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Pasa lo mismo si haces save en vez de saveOrUpdate?

Comment: Ala! Con un save si que funciona! No se me había ocurrido probarlo. Lo que la gracia del save or update es no tener que discriminar si es nuevo o no para hacer distintas operaciones. Pero de momento esto me lo soluciona. Gracias!

Comment: Sin dominar hibernate, se me ocurría que lo que pasa es que el saveOrUpdate primero intenta modificar las colecciones dependientes de la principal, y posteriormente es cuando hace el insert o update sobre la principal. Pero claro, en ese punto ya te ha fallado.